# Join between distinct datasources on SSRS

Tags: sql-server, oracle, reporting-services, db2, database-administration

I need to create on SSRS2016 a dataset that depends on two different datasources (Oracle & DB2). I found the following solution on the microsoft foruns, but it seems to be too complex:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31414.ssrs-merge-data-from-different-datasources-into-one-dataset-inside-ssrs-report.aspx

I believe an easier solution would be to create an SQL Server linked server that would allow me (from the SSRS point of view) to have a single data source (SQL Server). All the complexity would be in my SQL Server instance were a linked server would allow me to query the Oracle & DB2 instance. Do you believe this approach is feasible? A 3rd option would be to use individual calls to LookUpSet in order to do individual joins on each table (avoiding to create a dataset containing data from the two datasources).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937015/can-i-join-across-datasources-in-ssrs

Comment: Start with what you know first. Using linked servers in SQL Server would be the first logical choice to me. But try something first while you are waiting for the best answer here.

Comment: The easiest solution is the one you know how to do.   Aside from that, what makes you think any solution that works is "better" than another?